# Emulate engraved (text-shadow) on IE9 with CSS

Tags: internet-explorer-9, css

I would like to emulate engraved (text-shadow) in IE9

In chrome/FF I have follow css (http://jsfiddle.net/YbyzF/)

```
text-shadow: 0px 2px 0px rgba(255,255,255,.3), 0px -2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
```

But IE9 doesn't supports text-shadow

I tried to use :after, :before pseudo-elements, but :after element isn't under  in follow link (http://jsfiddle.net/chxfs/6/)

How to move :after element to required position for emulate 2 text-shadows in IE9?

Answer (score 0):

IE9 does not understand text-shadow property. You can use filter property instead:

```
text-shadow:0px 2px 0px black;
```

can be replaced with

```
filter: Shadow(Color=black, Direction=45, Strength=1);
```

Comment: Yes, but as i know - IE9 doesn't support 2 shadow on 1 element (I tried it earlier)